# Xcode simulator constantly download something

Tags: xcode, simulator

Xcode 11.2.1 simulator 13.2.2 constantly download something daily about 450 MB through nsurlsessiond. Is this usual? 
some logs

```
% sudo lsof | grep nsurlsessiond
Password:
UserEvent   60                   root  txt       REG                1,4      30016 1152921500312497946 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  cwd       DIR                1,4        736                   2 /
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4     614448 1152921500312495196 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4      28180            23592776 /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.99GYDmPS
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4   29062064 1152921500312497147 /usr/share/icu/icudt64l.dat
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4   10833920            23596379 /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv/com.apple.LaunchServices-1080-v2.csstore
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG                1,4    1558064 1152921500312496184 /usr/lib/dyld
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    0r      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    1u      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    2u      CHR                3,2        0t0                 310 /dev/null
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    3   NPOLICY                                                   
nsurlsess  215         _nsurlsessiond    5u    systm 0x1ebb302b93b87b91        0t0                     [ctl com.apple.netsrc id 7 unit 7]
UserEvent  311                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4      30016 1152921500312497946 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess  345                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4     614448 1152921500312495196 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
UserEvent 8964                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4      29984            23127670 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess 9001                 xxxx  txt       REG                1,4     761744            23119545 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
com.apple 9044                 xxxx    3w      REG                1,4   13597149            23603623 /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0685A70-DEB9-4786-8368-CF98BAC7FD1A/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.apple.mobileassetd/CFNetworkDownload_O3Y86b.tmp/AssetData/adat
xxxx@xxxx-iMac ~ %
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, any solution found?

Comment: Same issue here, haven't found any fix yet

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377220/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something

Answer (score 14):

Temporary solution based on this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114981):

rename the file  com.apple.nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/

to something -com.apple.nsurlsessiond

and also the file nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/

to something -nsurlsessiond

Comment: working but if you will found permanent solution then inform here

Comment: It's working fine for temporary solution, When I have installed XCode 12 it was starting again downloading

Comment: What does it mean rename nsurlsessiond to something -nsurlsessiond?

Comment: This disables my development server to communicate on the simulator, and app gets stuck on its splash screen for infinite time.