# How to stop Xcode simulator draining network data

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Every time I open Xcode Simulator it invokes an activity called `nsurlsessiond` and it drains my  network data. I just open simulator, I don't even make any api calls still it drains my network data.

I have restricted 1.5GB per day

The Xcode version is Version 11.2.1 (11B53).

I had deleted some of the simulators which I am not using.

Previously simulator wasn't draining data like this. Can anyone tell me why this is happening.

[image]

I got this output from the tcpDump file using Wireshark.
[image]

Comment: Can you take a tcpdump or otherwise capture network traffic to determine what data is being fetched?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I added the tcpdump.

Comment: Well... you added a screenshot of a snippet of a tcpdump.  That doesn't quite help much here ... other than possibly revealing that the traffic is to some http server (assuming the traffic captured in the screenshot is the traffic in question)...

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia this is the issue I am talking about https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114981

Comment: Found one temporary fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251235/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something

Comment: @anki yeah I had found one temporary fix for this problem. Which works just fine.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale I am also facing same daily around 1GB data drained, just fix your temporary 59251235, now no data drain but if u will receive any permanent fix then inform here

Comment: Glad it worked for you @iAj. I have noticed that the data drain only happens if you install Xcode by downloading and installing it manually. If you download from AppStore this doesn't happen.
Yeah if I get a permanent fix, I'll surely post it here.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale tnx, I will wait

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i find a temporary solution!

rename the file  com.apple.nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/

to something -com.apple.nsurlsessiond

and also the file nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/

to something -nsurlsessiond

Comment: i get permission denied although emulator is not running. how did you fix the permission problem?

Comment: deleting those files make me can't debugging, because simulator can't communicate with debug service

Comment: Not helping in my case, well now nothing works. (I'm using react-native and the server now got disconnected.)

Answer (score 1):

you could use bash script below which kills nsurlsessiond process. just copy it to *.sh file and run in terminal when you want to restrict nsurlsessiond activity.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; 
do 
    pid=$(pgrep "nsurlsessiond");
    if [[ ! -z "$pid" ]]; then
        echo "nsurlsessiond with PID:${pid} killed at $(date +'%X')";
        echo $(pkill "nsurlsessiond");
    fi
    sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: Thanks @wandersage. However, I set the delay to 2 seconds because within 10s, nsurlsessiond has time to restart and load several MB of data. Thanks to your tip I can stop the process when I have a limited internet connection.