# How to clean junk files in Xcode from iOS support

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, macos-big-sur

I have tried cleaning the simulator but it again occupies 6gb disk space on my Mac.
Can anyone suggest manual cleaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Delete the contents of `"~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/"`.
- Remove all "paired devices" in iOS settings > Developer.
- Connect iPhone to the Mac and pick "Don't trust".

---

Since the above is not okay for iTunes syncing etc, try the following:

Delete the contents of the folder `"~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/"` and then right click > get info > lock the folder.

Locking the folder will stop Xcode from copying the simulator files from the iPhone to that folder next time you connect them.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380024/how-to-stop-xcode-downloading-ios-support-package-of-my-iphone

---

It is possible that Xcode starts downloading it via `nsurlsessiod` so you can block it either

- by using a firewall

  - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393689/how-to-stop-catalina-from-contacting-apple-servers-when-executing-programs/393698#393698
- Or by renaming the binary as explained at the link below. (I haven't tried it)

  - [Xcode simulator constantly download something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251235/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something)

Comment: You can always unlock the folder. // the least destructive way is to select "don't trust" upon collection as listed in this answer. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380032/313842 // Firewall is also safe as long as the firewall app you use is safe. // I haven't used binary renaming, so cannot comment on that.

Comment: I've been using the folder lock + firewall for several months of daily Xcode usage and faced no issues.

Answer (score 10):

If the objective is to free up disk space occupied by Xcode-related and simulator-related caches and data, and not just iOS support files, there are other folders you can look into to consider removing files, besides `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/` and `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` that have been mentioned in the other 2 answers so far.

- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/` contains data from your builds that can be helpful in the process of symbolicating/debugging deployed apps, but could otherwise be removed. Thankfully, it is organized by date, so you can choose to keep specific folders inside it, and delete the rest
- `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/` contains simulator related data. It includes a `Caches` folder and a `Devices` folder. If you no longer need to run your apps on certain devices, you may consider removing those devices' corresponding folders in the `Devices` folder. The `Caches` folder may grow over time as well, and you can remove contents from there, and they should be regenerated as needed.
- If you've been using this machine for some years, it may be worth looking for `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`. The simulator related files used to be there until around Xcode 6. So you may have files still there that you might want to delete (I did, on some older Macs some years back)
- There's an Xcode specific cache (not about simulators), `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`, which should be regenerated as needed, but may be less useful to clean up.

You could also consider running [DevCleaner](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12) from time to time to remove unnecessary Xcode-related files.

Comment: I have executed all your mentioned locations but none of them is showing any response I can't get rid of space form my system

Comment: I wasn't listing commands, but locations/folders.

Comment: yes I meant that but they aren't getting deleted even after draging them into bin its showing me false deletion expectations

Comment: Some of the folders may be re-created after you drag them to the Trash in this way, but you can try removing just the contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234742/discussion-between-yash-chitroda-and-auspicious99).

Answer (score 2):

Command-Option-Shift-K to clean out the build folder. Even better, quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually. Remove all its contents because there's a bug where Xcode will run an old version of your project that's in there somewhere
By following this steps you can do....